# static в конструкторах java

Tags: java

Можно ли выводить значение `i` , при этом не указывая её как `static int i` ?

```
public class A {
    static int i;

    A (int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    B(int i) {
        super(i);
    }

    public static void main(String args []) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста, начал заниматься джавой совсем недавно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого вам нужно создать экземпляр класса, и `i` уже будет являться полем созданного экземпляра:

```
public class A {

    int i;

    A(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
}

class B extends A {

    B(int i) {
        super(i);
    }

    public static void main(String args []){
        B b = new B(2);
        System.out.print(b.i);
    }
}
```

**UPD.** исправил `B` на `b` в выводе

Comment: Скопировал всё как у вас, выдает Error:(9, 27) java: non-static variable i cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: извиняюсь, там в последней строке `main` `b.i`, а не `B.i` конечно же

Answer (score 4):

Из статического метода `main()` можно вызывать **только** статические методы/переменные. Так что ответ очевиден - нельзя.